# HTTP request from angular is not hitting .Net web API ActionMethod

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have applied JWT authentication on .net successfully & the result is quite fine when I use postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skCdJ.png)

but when I called it from angular using the same Url it shows an error because it's not hitting the Actionresult of web API from angular. Following are the code Please help me out.[gu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/339Ab.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDajH.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. And you haven't shown the Angular implementation yet.

Comment: `when I called it from angular using the same Url it shows an error` Please share the code that you are using to make request on angular client, and please check the status code of the request on browser network tab.

Answer (score 1):

That should be url in your angular app : `http://localhost/59912/api/account/login`. Currently you are using end point `http://localhost/59912/login` which would not match and also does not match what you are using in postman.

Comment: I had used the same URL http://localhost/59912/api/account/Login in my angular app the problem is I was expecting the Email or Password from the angular app but unfortunately  I was passing Email or UserPassword, as Password or UserPassword is not matching the action method is not triggered now the problem is solved. by the way thanks for the reply.